# Can a python generator use recursion?

Tags: python, generator

```
>>> def gen(num):
...     print "inside \n"
...     if num < 10:
...         gen(num +1)
...     yield num
... 
>>> x = gen(1)
>>> for i in x:
...     print i
... 
inside

1
>>>
```

Why is inside printed only once? I thought it would get printed many more times.

Comment: To answer your title question: yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only created the recursive generator, you never *iterated over it*. If you don't ask a generator for values, it'll never execute.

Add a loop and yield the results of the recursive call:

```
def gen(num):
    print "inside"
    if num < 10:
        for recursive_result in gen(num + 1):
            yield recursive_result
    yield num
```

This produces:

```
>>> def gen(num):
...     print "inside"
...     if num < 10:
...         for recursive_result in gen(num + 1):
...             yield recursive_result
...     yield num
... 
>>> x = gen(1)
>>> for i in x:
...     print i
... 
inside 
inside 
inside 
inside 
inside 
inside 
inside 
inside 
inside 
inside 
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

You are evidently using Python 2, but if you were to use Python 3.3 you can make use of [generator delegation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380) and instead of looping use [`yield from`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr):

```
def gen(num):
    print("inside")
    if num < 10:
        yield from gen(num + 1)
    yield num
```

Comment: It's worth noting that since 3.3, `yield from` exists to make this even easier.